# Ajax form , PHP process and return errors if there's any , if not success

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I found a tutorial here : http://tutorialzine.com/2009/08/creating-a-facebook-like-registration-form-with-jquery/ (please take a look)

It's a nice tutorial, I followed everything there and remove extra stuff I don't want , like the functions.php with **generate_function option** as I am not in need of birthday etc. stuff.

All I want is a NAME(usrname) , EMAIL(email) , Password(password) , when the user click on "REGISTER" button (which is the form submit button), the script I got from the tutorial will send the data over to "regprocess.php" which contains validation check codes like checking if the submitted form data is empty.

But when I click REGISTER , the data is not sent back (the error message) from the "regprocess.php" nor the success message. 
When i check with my firebug , **the JSON response is showing the full php code like the one below(scroll down).**

Here's my code :
HTML-

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="register.js"></script>
    <form id="regForm" action="regprocess.php" method="post">
          <label for="usrname">Name:</label>
          <input id="usrname" name="usrname" type="text" value="" class="nor">
          <label for="email">Email:</label>
          <input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="" class="nor">
          <label for="password">Password:</label>
          <input id="password" name="password" type="password" value="" class="nor">
    <table><tr><td style="width:290px;"><div id="error">&nbsp;</div></td><td><input name="register" type="submit" value="Register" id="regbtn"><center><img id="loading" src="images/load.gif" alt="Registering..." /></center></td></tr></table>
    </form>
```

Okay the Ajax script is in "register.js" above.

Ajax script(register.js)-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#regForm').submit(function(e) {
                register();
        e.preventDefault();
        });
});

function register()
{
    hideshow('loading',1); 
        hideshow('regbtn',0);
    error(0);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "regprocess.php",
        data: $('#regForm').serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg){

            if(parseInt(msg.status)==1)
            {
                window.location=msg.txt;
            }
            else if(parseInt(msg.status)==0)
            {
                error(1,msg.txt);
            }

            hideshow('loading',0);
                        hideshow('regbtn',1);
        }
    });

}

function hideshow(el,act)
{
    if(act) $('#'+el).css('visibility','visible');
    else $('#'+el).css('visibility','hidden');
}

function error(act,txt)
{
    hideshow('error',act);
    if(txt) $('#error').html(txt);
}
```

CSS:
Regbtn is the submit button , it's visibility is set to visible
loading is set to hidden
error is set to hidden

When a user click on Regbtn , loading visibility will become visible while Regbtn hides(visibility:hidden).

It's done in the Ajax script(register.js).

Okay now the php:
PHP(regprocess.php)-

```
if(empty($_POST['usrname']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['password']))
{
    die('{status:0,"txt":"Fill in All Fields"}');
}


if(!(preg_match("/^[\.A-z0-9_\-\+]+[@][A-z0-9_\-]+([.][A-z0-9_\-]+)+[A-z]{1,4}$/", $_POST['email'])))
    die('{status:0,"txt":"Please Provide a Valid Email"}');

echo '{status:1,txt:"registered.html"}';
```

This checks whether the username , email and password data is empty , if yes , returns a message which will be displayed in the Error(#error in html) , it also checks whether email provided is valid.

If everything else is right , user will be directed to **registered.html**

But i think the script can't get the error message back from the php.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks.
Have a nice day.

Comment: and the answer? where is the answer?

Comment: the jSON answer .. doh! What do you see in firebug?

Comment: the JSON response is showing the full PHP code instead f the status , for example : {status:0,"txt":"Fill in All Fields"}

Comment: that's not he full php code, that's the answer ...

Comment: yes its my full php code , look at the tutorial , its the same , i just took out the birthday and some.

Answer (score 0):

hmm not too much of an answer but what I do on my forms is a I submit via ajax and put the result from the php page in the parent of the form.
below is the plugin in code. it works when the form is a child of a div by default.

```
(function($){
$.fn.extend({
//pass the options variable to the function
ajaxForm: function(options) 
{
    //Set the default values, use comma to separate the settings, example:
    var defaults = 
    {
        target: 'div'
    }
    var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);

    return this.each(function() 
    {
        var o=options
        $(this).submit(function(event)
        {
            event.preventDefault();//stop from submiting
            //set needed variables
            var $form = $(this)
            var $div = $form.parent(o.target)
            $url = $form.attr("action");
            //submit via post and put results in div
            $.post( $url, $form.serialize() , function(data) 
            { $div.html(data) })
        })
    });
}
}); 
})(jQuery);
```

note this will run for every form so change it as you would wish.
whatever you want to display just echo on the php page. also this is made for post and the php page will access anything just like any other form being with post.
also it wouldn't be hard to modify if you felt necessary to send as json instead.

Comment: it would run  by including it and then $('selector').ajaxForm()

Comment: it will out put whatever you have echod on the php page. so for instance if you wanted an error message. echo 'user name is already taken'; whatever php echos will be written in place of the form. If you want you can also echo the whole form and just add the errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put php tags around the php code, like this:

```
<?php
if(empty($_POST['usrname']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['password']))
{
    die('{status:0,"txt":"Fill in All Fields"}');
}


if(!(preg_match("/^[\.A-z0-9_\-\+]+[@][A-z0-9_\-]+([.][A-z0-9_\-]+)+[A-z]{1,4}$/", $_POST['email'])))
    die('{status:0,"txt":"Please Provide a Valid Email"}');

echo '{status:1,txt:"registered.html"}';
?>
```